# Regex Preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, bbcode

I'm trying to do a preg_replace to convert come bbcode.  Basically, this

```
[QUOTE=ksiva]blahblah blah[/QUOTE]
```

Needs to look like this

```
<div class=quote-msg"><div class="quote-author"><em>ksiva</em></div>blahblah blah</div>
```

I tried this preg replace, but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
$pattern = '#\[QUOTE=([a-zA-Z]*|\#?[0-9a-fA-F]{6})](.*?)\[/QUOTE\]#s';

$replace = '<div class="quote-msg"><div class="quote-author><em>$1</em></div>$2</div>';
$text = PREG_REPLACE($pattern, $replace, $text);
```

Comment: What might the `[QUOTE=name]` part look like? Could it be just `[QUOTE]` or does it have to have a name? What will the names look like?

Comment: This works fine - the only thing is that you're not putting a double quote after `<div class="quote-author` - fix that and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Pop in this code, I think it's what you're looking for.

```
$pattern = '/\[QUOTE\=([^]]*)]([^\[]*)\[\/QUOTE]/';
$text = '[QUOTE=ksiva]blahblah blah[/QUOTE]';
$replace = "<div class=\"quote-msg\"><div class=\"quote-author\"><em>$1</em></div>$2</div>";
$text = PREG_REPLACE($pattern, $replace, $text);
```